# How to format a number in Entity Framework LINQ (without trailing zeroes)?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

In a SQL Server database I have a column of `decimal` datatype defined something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    Id INT,
    Number DECIMAL(9, 4)
)
```

I use Entity Framework and I would like to return column `Number` converted to a string with only the digits right of the decimal separator that are actually needed. A strict constraint is that a result must be an `IQueryable`.

So my query is:

```
IQueryable queryable = (
            from myTable in MyDatabase.NyTable
            select new
            {
                Id = myTable.Id,
                Number = SqlFunctions.StringConvert(myTable.Number,9,4)
            }
);
```

The problem with is that it always convert number to string with 4 decimals, even if they are 0.

Examples:

- 3 is converted to "3.0000"
- 1.2 is converted to "1.2000"

If I use other parameters for `StringConvert` i.e.

```
SqlFunctions.StringConvert(myTable.Number, 9, 2)
```

the results are also not OK:

- 0.375 gets rounded to 0.38.

`StringConvert()` function is translated into SQL Server function `STR`.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

This explains the weird results.

In the realm of Entity Framework and LINQ I was not able to find a working solution.

What I look for is something like C# function

```
String.Format("0.####", number)
```

but this cannot be used in a LINQ query.

In plain simple SQL I could write my query like this

```
SELECT
    Id,
    Number = CAST(CAST(Number AS REAL) AS VARCHAR(15))
FROM
    MyTable
```

I have not managed to massage LINQ to produce query like that.

A workaround would be to forget doing this in LINQ, which is quite inflexible and messy thing, borderline on useless and just return type DECIMAL from database and do my formatting on a client side before displaying. But this is additional, unnecessary code and I would hate to di it that way if there perhaps is a simpler way via LINQ.

Is it possible to format numbers in LINQ queries?

Comment: number formatting is not supported in l2sql, you'll have to do the formatting on client side or get the formatted string via raw sql.

Answer (score 1):

I would absolutely return a decimal from he database and format it when needed. Possible directly after the query. But usually this is done at display time to take into account culture specific formatting from the the client.

```
var q = 
    (from myTable in MyDatabase.NyTable
    select new
    {
        Id = myTable.Id,
        Number = myTable.Number
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, Number = x.Number.ToString("G29") });
```

Comment: Usage of AsEnumerable() is a no go. My result must IQueryable.

Comment: Than I would do it at display time, and also take into account the clients culture specific formatting. That wont work if the conversion is performed in the db.